# synonymise dateutil -> python-dateutil

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

As the title says really: I believe [dateutil](/questions/tagged/dateutil) should be synonymous with [python-dateutil](/questions/tagged/python-dateutil) which is a little bit more explicit re: the language and has a better wiki entry.

Possibly, as there's only 54 [dateutil](/questions/tagged/dateutil) - move them all to [python-dateutil](/questions/tagged/python-dateutil) for consistency.

Does anyone think this would cause issues, or otherwise think this would not be a good thing to do?

Update:

As Dave Newton has pointed out - this also has context in Java... however, the only Java related [dateutil](/questions/tagged/dateutil) is [DateUtils.parseDate exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794247/dateutils-parsedate-exception)

Comment: I'm not psyched about a "dateutil" tag since there's at least one JS library named that, and Java classes in a few projects. If anything I'd migrate and burninate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now retagged all [dateutil](/questions/tagged/dateutil) questions to [python-dateutil](/questions/tagged/python-dateutil) ... any chance someone could synonimize?

Comment: I see 4 survivors but I'm not familiar with python-dateutil, are those to be retagged as well?

Comment: @madth3 fixed ([tag:pandas] is in my ignorelist, so I missed those 4).